# Convert String in Array form to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

Let's say I've got a string with three strings looking like this:

```
String s = "[object1,object2,object3]";
```

How do I convert this to a String array which looks like this:

```
String[] ary = {"object1", "object2", "object3"};
```

Also mind that each string item (`object1`, `object2` and `object3`) may also contain additional comma (`,`) characters.

Comment: Are those just string values (`"object1"`) or are they meant to represent variable names?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just string values.

Comment: @Zeromus I rejected your edit suggestion for two reasons: changing the items to "a", "b" and "c" isn't helpful and calling them "character" is also misleading, since each item is more than just a single character. But it is very nice to see, that you like to help to improve questions on this page. Please keep doing that.

Answer (score 2):

just use the `split` method `String[] str = s.split(",");`
if you want  the "[ ]" out use the string.replace method to replace "[]" with ""

Comment: either this or use a regex

Comment: @Zeromus Alright, but what if my string already contains commas like ","? Lets say I have converted an array (with jsons converted to strings) to a string, and then I want to convert it back?

Comment: @MarkTyers Then it is obiviously impossible to split these strings.

Comment: @MarkTyers do you mean "object,1,object,2,object,3" then is impossible as Tom said. you need to be clear what you want to achieve with this

Comment: @MarkTyers *"Lets say I have converted an array (with jsons converted to strings) to a string, and then I want to convert it back?"* If this is the real reason why you ask this question, then say that in the question and provide a proper example? This would result in better answers for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

To do the stuff in your situation you can do

```
String[] ary = s.substring(1, s.length() -1).split(",");
```

If there is no "[" and "]" just remove the substring call

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want don't want the outer `[]`, you could use replace/split or substring/split

```
String myArray[] = s.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
```

Or

```
String myArray[] = s.substring(1, s.length() -1 ).split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below with comments to explain what each does.

```
s = s.replace("[","").replace("]},""); //remove the brackets
String[] ary = s.split(",");           //split the string around commas
```